# How to add styling to tabs of prime-ng tabview in angular 6?

Tags: css, angular, primeng, ng-bootstrap

I am using prime-ng tabView and current tabview is like this
[image]

And I want to achieve the following type of tabs for the tabView.
[image]

Is there a way to achieve this?

The basic p-tabview implementation is like this.

```
<p-tabView [(activeIndex)]="currentTab">
        <p-tabPanel header="Tab1"  ></p-tabPanel>
        <p-tabPanel header="Tab2"  ></p-tabPanel>
        <p-tabPanel header="Tab3"  ></p-tabPanel>
        <p-tabPanel header="Tab4"  ></p-tabPanel>
        <p-tabPanel header="Tab5"  ></p-tabPanel>
</p-tabView>
```

Comment: please share code and show us what you tried so far

Comment: Prime-ng is a third party library, and it does not provide these kind of styling. So I thought of asking a question if anybody has gone through such scenario